# R Regex get capital letters substrings

Tags: r, regex

I want to use `gsub` to get the tail substrings that have at least 2 consecutive capital letters within a string. Perhaps it's easier to demonstrate in a few examples:

```
"my_BONNIE" -> "ONNIE"
"Billing_ID" -> "D"
"OPT" -> "PT"
```

Here is my try that doesn't work:

```
> gsub("[^(A-Z)][A-Z]([A-Z]+)", "\\1", "BillingTableIDE")
[1] "BillingTablDE"
```

EDIT:

Got this to work for single capital "subword" like so:

```
gsub("([A-Z])([A-Z]+)", paste0("\\1", tolower(
     gsub(".*(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]([A-Z]+)", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE))), x)
```

But this doesn't work if there are multiple capital "subwords" like so:

```
# Does
"ABC_DEF" -> "Aef_Def"
# When it should be doing
"ABC_DEF" -> "Abc_Def"
```

Comment: I do not understand the rule, but [`sub(".*(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]([A-Z]+)", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZwJiJs/2) provides the expected results.

Comment: What about [`(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/S6uPWL/3)?

Comment: I don't know if gsub requires matching from beginning, but if not, a simple `(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+` works without any fanfare.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern needs to match the whole string, if you want to replace the whole string with part of it:

```
gsub(".*?[A-Z]([A-Z]+)$", "\\1", "BillingTableIDE")
# [1] "DE"
```

While your pattern only matches:

```
BillingTableIDE
#          ^^^^  and this gets replaced with DE
# so you have BillingTablDE
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr).

```
library(stringr)

test <- c("my_BONNIE", "Billing_ID", "OPT")

test2 <- str_extract(test, "[A-Z]+$")

test3 <- str_sub(test2, 2)

test3
# [1] "ONNIE" "D"     "PT"
```